# docker-composer node js give error when running the docker composer . mysql ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to deploy my node js application with docker but when I am running the docker compose it giving an error at the end. 
I saw some solution like

```sql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'
```

, but where to specify this query in the docker.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile-mysql
    container_name: mydb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbautokab
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
    networks:
      - helicopter-network
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"

  helicopter-api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile-api
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks: ['helicopter-network']
    environment:
        - PORT=3000
        - DATABASE_HOST=db
        - DATABASE_PASSWORD=
        - EGG_SERVER_ENV=local
        - NODE_ENV=development
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

networks:
  helicopter-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**Dockerfile-api**

```
FROM node:10-slim

USER node

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY --chown=node package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node . .

COPY wait-for-it.sh /

ENV HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=3000

EXPOSE ${PORT}

CMD /wait-for-it.sh db:3306 -- npm start
```

**Dockerfile-mysql**

```
FROM mysql 

COPY ./docker/init_db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**init_db.sql**

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS dbautokab;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on dbautokab.*
TO 'root'@'%'
WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

**error**

> error when connecting to db: { Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE:
>   Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server;
>   consider upgrading MySQL client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use:

> FROM mysql

Docker pull the latest version, in this case (8.0) that does not support type of authentication

You can specify version tag on you Dockerfile like :

> FROM mysql:5.7.26

If you want to stay in Mysql 8.0.

You should execute this command line inside container:

> docker exec -it container_name mysql -u root -p [root-password] mysql -e "update user set authentication_string=password(''), plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';"

Or connect to your container and execute the command:

> docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash
>   mysql -u root -p [root-password] mysql -e "update user set authentication_string=password(''), plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';"

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks it works but now i am getting new issue . I have posted new question for it. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56664660/mysql-give-error-when-running-the-docker-composer-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that starting the server with a custom default authentication plugin should do the trick. In this case, you can override the `command` property in `docker-compose.yml`.

```
# ...
services:
  db:
    # ...
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    # ...
```